# MongoDB - Add / update to list of objects on document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a user collection, and each user has a list of products. I need to update a product using it's ID or add the product if it doesn't exist.

How can I update the product by it's id?

**User Collection:**

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5fc06554266266edf5643231"
    },
    "products": [
        {
            "id": 123,
            "name": "test product"
        }
    ]
}
```

Using the following code I'm able to add the product, but can't update the product by it's ID.

```
db.users.updateOne({_id: ObjectId('5fc06554266266edf5643231')}, {
  '$addToSet': {
    'products': {
      'id': 123,
      'name': 'foobar'
    }
  }
}, {upsert:true})
```

Comment: Are you using the Mongo shell?

Comment: @MontgomeryWatts yes

Answer (score 0):

Well, i will recommend to you to re-think your schema.

Maybe you need to create a collection called Products and in the user collection put all the id's of the products on a field called product. Then you can create a query with a populate function. Something like this

```
const user = await User.find(query, options)
.then(async (result) => result)
.catch((err) => logger.info(err));
  
  const populateProducts = await Products.populate(user, populateProductsOptions)
    .then(async (data) => data)
    .catch((err) => logger.info(err));
```

Answer (score 0):

But if you don't want to modify your schema you have to do several querys. There is no way to do this in single query. You have to search the document first:

If document exist:

```
db.users.updateOne( {_id: 123456 , yourQueryProduct , 
                false , 
                true);

db.users.updateOne( {_id: 123456: 123456 } , 
                {$pull: {"items" : {'item_name' : "my_item_two" , 'price' : 1 }} } ,
                false , 
                true);

db.users.updateOne( {_id: 123456: 123456 } , 
                {$addToSet : {"items" : {'item_name' : "my_item_two" , 'price' : 1 }} } ,
                false , 
                true);
```

else if document don't exist you can addToSet directly

Comment: I understand removing and adding it, but what does the first statement do?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that on this line: `db.users.updateOne({_id: "5fc06554266266edf5643231"}`

The `_id` field is being interpreted as a String, but the document you want to update saves its `_id` as an ObjectId. All you have to do it make it an ObjectId is this:

```
db.users.updateOne({_id: ObjectId("5fc06554266266edf5643231")}, {
  '$addToSet': {
    'products': {
      'id': 123,
      'name': 'foobar'
    }
  }
}, {upsert:true})
```

Comment: That's one of my issues fixed, but if the product name changes I need to save it to the existing document and not add another one to the list.

Comment: @millerg I'm not sure that there's a way to do this in a single command that handles both updates and inserts the way the data is structured. [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/#value-to-add-is-a-document) considers the entire document, so two documents with different `name` fields are different. Attempting to remove any products with a matching id and adding to the product array in the same operation is also impossible.